# Modified quicksort exceeded maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I try to recreate modified quicksort from here https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-15-6648-6_26#enumeration

the code give this error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
when array length > 9

here is my code

```
def quick_sort(arr,low,high):
    n = high-low+1
    if n<=3:
        manual_sort(arr,low,high)
    else:
        a = calculate_pivot(arr,low,high)
        q = partition(arr,low,high,a)
        quick_sort(arr,low,q)
        quick_sort(arr,q+1,high)
```

```
def calculate_pivot(arr,low,high):
    temp_arr = arr[low:high+1]
    #print(temp_arr)
    left_arr = temp_arr[:len(temp_arr)//2]
    right_arr = temp_arr[len(temp_arr)//2:]
    avg_left = (max(left_arr)+min(left_arr))/len(left_arr)
    avg_right = (max(right_arr)+min(right_arr))/len(right_arr)
    return (avg_left+avg_right)/2
```

```
def manual_sort(arr,low,high):
    n = high-low+1
    if n<=1:
        return
    if n==2:
        if arr[low]>arr[high]:
            arr[low] = arr[low] + arr[high]
            arr[high] = arr[low] - arr[high]
            arr[low] = arr[low] - arr[high]
    if n==3:
        if arr[low]>arr[high-1]:
            arr[low] = arr[low] + arr[high-1]
            arr[high-1] = arr[low] - arr[high-1]
            arr[low] = arr[low] - arr[high-1]
    if arr[low]>arr[high]:
        arr[low] = arr[low] + arr[high]
        arr[high] = arr[low] - arr[high]
        arr[low] = arr[low] - arr[high]
    if arr[high-1]>arr[high]:
        arr[high-1] = arr[high-1] + arr[high]
        arr[high] = arr[high-1] - arr[high]
        arr[high-1] = arr[high-1] - arr[high]
```

```
def partition(arr,low,high,pivot):
    i = low-1
    j = high+1
    while 1:
        i+=1
        while arr[i]<pivot:
            i+=1
        j-=1
        while arr[j]>pivot:
            j-=1
        if i>=j:
            return j
        arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
```

i notice this paper use some kind of hoare partition scheme so I try to compare with this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/ but i still can't find what's wrong

Comment: Assuming your partition is correct, you can limit recursion depth to O(log n) by only recurring on the smaller partition. See the [first bullet point here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Optimizations).

Comment: @Blastfurnace good information, but I think here is a case where they are entering infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

For Hoare partition scheme, the pivot value must be an actual value in the sub-array being partitioned, not an average. In this code, I used the middle value for pivot. With this particular implementation of partition, any value other than arr[high] can be used for the pivot. Using arr[high] with this implementation will typically lead to infinite recursion or looping in the second code example (because partition will return q == high). I also fixed some other bits in this code:

```
def quick_sort(arr,low,high):
    n = high-low+1
    if n<=3:
        manual_sort(arr,low,high)
    else:
        a = calculate_pivot(arr,low,high)
        q = partition(arr,low,high,a)
        quick_sort(arr,low,q)
        quick_sort(arr,q+1,high)

def calculate_pivot(arr,low,high):
    return arr[(low+high)//2]

def manual_sort(arr,low,high):
    n = high-low+1
    if n<=1:
        return
    if n==2:
        if arr[low]>arr[high]:
            arr[low] = arr[low] + arr[high]
            arr[high] = arr[low] - arr[high]
            arr[low] = arr[low] - arr[high]
    if n==3:
        if arr[low]>arr[high-1]:
            arr[low] = arr[low] + arr[high-1]
            arr[high-1] = arr[low] - arr[high-1]
            arr[low] = arr[low] - arr[high-1]
        if arr[low]>arr[high]:
            arr[low] = arr[low] + arr[high]
            arr[high] = arr[low] - arr[high]
            arr[low] = arr[low] - arr[high]
        if arr[high-1]>arr[high]:
            arr[high-1] = arr[high-1] + arr[high]
            arr[high] = arr[high-1] - arr[high]
            arr[high-1] = arr[high-1] - arr[high]

def partition(arr,low,high,pivot):
    i = low-1
    j = high+1
    while 1:
        while 1:
            i+=1
            if(arr[i]>=pivot):
                break
        while 1:
            j-=1
            if(arr[j]<=pivot):
                break
        if i>=j:
            return j
        arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
```

To prevent stack overflow, recurse on the smaller partition, loop back for the larger partition. This limits stack complexity to O(log(n)), but worst case time complexity remains at O(n^2).

```
def quick_sort(arr,low,high):
    while((high-low) >= 3):
        a = calculate_pivot(arr,low,high)
        q = partition(arr,low,high,a)
        if((q+1-low) <= (high-q)):
            quick_sort(arr,low,q)
            low = q+1
        else:
            quick_sort(arr,q+1,high)
            high = q
    manual_sort(arr,low,high)
```